# SQL Inheritance with triggers automated

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inheritance, triggers

So my problem, which i just can't figure out on how to do is this.

I have a table `Product` which consists on `productid` and various other attributes.
I also have the table `clothing`, which has the attribute `size`, and `accesoire`, which has the attribute `color`.
`clothing` doesnt't have the attribute `color`, and `accesoire` doesn't have the attribute `size` and both inherit from the table `Product`.

Now i want to make it so, when i insert a `product`, with the type `clothing`, a trigger will automatically insert an entry into `Clothing`.
However, if i would insert a `product`, i would not be able to pass on the attribute `size` to the database because the `Product` table doesn't have this attribute.

SO my issue is basically, how do i insert a subtype using a trigger in the supertype, where the subtype would also need their specific attributes filled in.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Inside the trigger, most RDBMS's usually provide pseudo-rows for inserted / new and outgoing / old versions of the data - you can use applicable keys in these rows to join back to other tables in the database and retrieve the data needed for the trigger insert. If you can be more specific, so can we :) - e.g. which Sql RDBMS (MySql, Oracle, SqlServer etc)?

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that the additional subtype data will not be available to the trigger in the `Product` table, unless you add additional columns to Product (i.e. change the inheritance model to use table per hierarchy, instead of the table per class approach).

However, I believe that a trigger is *not* the correct approach to the primary insertion of data into the sub class tables `Clothing` and `Accesoire`.

I would recommend you encapsulate the insertion of data into the three tables via a Stored Procedure, such as the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertProduct(IN name VARCHAR(20), IN type CHAR(1), 
                               IN size INT, IN color VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
  DECLARE newID INT;
  INSERT INTO Product(Name, Type) VALUES(Name, Type);
  SET newID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  IF (type = 'C') THEN
    INSERT INTO Clothing(ProductID, Size) VALUES(newID, size);
  ELSE
     INSERT INTO Accesoire(ProductID, Color) VALUES(newID, color);
  END IF;
END;
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c31a4/1) here

Comment: Thank you very much stuart! This really helped me understand stored procedures and triggers!